# Table blocked on YQL?

Tags: api, yahoo, yql

I'm trying to retrieve a user timeline from Twitter using YQL's community Twitter table. The full REST url is

```
https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20twitter.status.timeline.home%20WHERE%20oauth_consumer_key%20%3D%20'kt9wDTrDREjXzRhBMpw'%20AND%20oauth_consumer_secret%20%3D%20'zNnA76G3NhZSeaJdRv7munbyutlcqK8k0hazf6JrEo'%20AND%20oauth_token%20%3D%20'195tuy9661-yJFEsgA0VPCwg6gsNHtuy2y2Kq2LwTdKe4BRYa4j'%20AND%20oauth_token_secret%20%3D%20'myWfyDTtOHscMmJy6tuyU1XDyiZJiIIRkK7sIPvT2ngI'&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys
```

(keys have been mangled to protect the guilty)

The response I get is:

> The current table
>   'twitter.status.timeline.user' has
>   been blocked. It exceeded the allotted
>   quotas of either time or instructions

As I seem to be doing the querying correctly, I'm at a bit of a loss as to why I should get this response, particularly since it works as it should through the YQL console. The only thing I can think of is that I need to authorize my query somehow with an API key, or oAuth credentials, but I haven't been able to find a comprehensible example of how to do this.

Can anyone possibly point me in the right direction on this? YQL's community tables seem to offer a marvelous way to do very complicated things with ease, so I'd hate to fall at the last hurdle so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

According to the twitter docs the call to this API endpoint is supposed to return the last tweets from the authorized user, right? Not from any kind of user. Just checking that this is really what you want to achieve.

From: http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/home_timeline

> Returns the 20 most recent statuses,
>   including retweets if they exist,
>   posted by the authenticating user and
>   the user's they follow. This is the
>   same timeline seen by a user when they
>   login to twitter.com.

This is the definition of the datatable that you are using. I am a bit confused about the @id parameter in the example of that datatable because I don't see it being used anywhere.

[www.datatables.org/twitter/twitter.status.timeline.home.xml](http://www.datatables.org/twitter/twitter.status.timeline.home.xml)

The error message you get sounds like an internal YQL error message and not like something that comes from Twitter, doesn't it?

Sorry for not being able to provide answer right now but maybe raising other related questions can help somebody else or you to figure it out. If I crack this later I will add to this again.